# Finding Function of Series: $e^{-kx}$

Tags: power-series

If the series representation of $e^{-x}$ is:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k}{k!} $$

Then what is for $e^{-kx}$?

Comment: Do you know the basic rules for constructing new power series from old ones? Also, slight nitpick but you don't want to use k as a summation index and a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a different index of summation than variables used outside the scope of the summation.
$$
e^{-kx}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-kx)^j}{j!}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the summation $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \text{.}$$ You demonstrated that you already know that you're allowed to replace $x$ with $-x$ to obtain the summation $$e^{-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!} \text{.}$$

Intuitively you should be able to throw a k in there as well: $$e^{-kx} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-kx)^n}{n!} \text{.}$$

Comment: Are these approximations good only in a small region around x= 0 ? or would be true for all x ?